# Javascript library for graphs (in the mathematical sense)

Tags: javascript, networking, graph, shortest-path

Are there any significant Javascript libraries for graph and network representation, with common algorithms, optimization, etc.?  I'm imagining something like the [C++ lemon library](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon), with graph search, shortest path, maximum flow, and so on.

Google draws a blank, because the results are completely flooded with graph- and chart-drawing libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in Cytoscape.js, an open-source JS graph theory library.  It can be run headlessly or with an interactive visualisation.  It is styleable via CSS-like files, has built in gestures, support for touch devices, node.js, etc.

There's a bunch of algorithms now, and there will be many more shortly -- i.e. more complex algorithms like PageRank etc.

http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/

Disclaimer: I work on the project

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at http://www.graphdracula.net/

It's got a number of algorithms including:

- bellman-ford
- dijkstra
- floyd-warshall

Comment: I saw this and dismissed it as another graph-drawing library.  Perhaps I was slightly wrong -- however, see [the source](https://github.com/strathausen/dracula/blob/master/js/dracula_algorithms.js) -- the algorithms haven't actually been written!

Comment: I believe all the ones I mentioned were implemented in the snapshot version. The network flow ones haven't been yet. Though to be honest, it wouldn't be terribly difficult to implement them yourself. Think of it as a good/fun exercise :)

Comment: With all the time in the world, it would be a wonderful exercise.

Answer (score 1):

[node-dijkstra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-dijkstra)

A NodeJS implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm

Answer (score -7):

Study a graph, generally require a lot of computer effort, expecially for large graph (I don't know what kind of graph you are trying to analyze) but if it is simple, probably you didn't need libraries. 
**You will never find what you're looking for**... it's even difficult to find something like that for the common languages, I don't think that  a scripting language studied to render HTML page can help you, expecially because it lives embedded in a browser that is neither studied nor capable to have the proper performance to your purposes.
I'm sure that you're only way is programming and perform analyzes on your graph through a server side programming language, in this case you will have a dedicated machine that performs operation on a graph and it has more sense.
I suggest you .NET because you can use your lemon library ... By the way have you ever tried **SNAP** http://snap.stanford.edu/ it's the best library you will ever find, I really suggest as a C++ library... take care that it lacks on documentation.
I'm sorry for javascript, but you will realize that I'm right

Comment: "difficult to find something like that for the common languages" -- not really. [More C++](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/index.html), [Java](http://www.jgrapht.org/), [Python](http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/), [Ruby](http://rgl.rubyforge.org/rgl/index.html), ... I could go on.  Graphs are fundamental data structures.

"a scripting language studied to render HTML page [...] it lives embedded in a browser" -- contra: NodeJS, etc.  In any case, why would web applications never require graphs?

Comment: If you read carefully my post, you will notice that I talk about library, so it's difficult to find some prebuilt advanced library for the common languages (I found some in C++ few in Java and not performan). I don't know what you mean, but for graph analyzer's library, I mean something able to get the diameter of a social network, calculate the distance from you and someone else or count the cluster indside an huge network. Are you able to make a javascript program that if you throw away halve of the node of an open social network say LiveJournal, it count how many cluster exists. Good Luck !

Comment: I never told that web application never require graph, I meant that handle the graph theory by a client side scripting language could not be so straightforward if the graph is consistent.